# google wmt: lost a lot of links to our site

Tags: seo, google-search, google-search-console

I've been having problems recently with my site and Google. There have been a number of problems (robots.txt etc.) which I fixed and resubmitted my main page & related pages via WMT. that worked fine.

But since then (2 days ago) I've lost most of the links to my site!

We have a major affiliate that had a lot of links to our site and now they don't appear in 
WMT "Links to your site".

We haven't received a warning mail about "unnatural links"
the links from the other site are alive (most of them to our home page, is that a problem)

Any ideas on how to fix this or what's causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It's one of two things:

1. You haven't fixed your indexing/exclusion problems correctly and something is causing that problem. Check again.
2. If not, remember that Google changes which links it displays and which it does not display basically according to their whim and updates. It's worth remembering the following things:

   - Just because a link is reported in WMT does not mean it is a good link.
   - Just because a link is NOT reported in WMT does not mean it is a bad link.
   - Overall number of links can only be used as a trend. The appearance or disappearance of a site reporting links means very little in the grand scheme of things.
   - Affiliate links are generally not a Google favourite for passing value. It's possible that your affiliate got hammered by Google.

Have your traffic and positions been affected? Then you're looking at a more major issue. If not, it's just Google being Google.